# How to receive and display all friends from friendlist in android chat app more efficiently

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been working on a chat app which I will be publishing soon on google play store. So my problem is that while retrieveing the friends from the firebase database. I look for every user id using my app and then if it matches with my friends id I display the id. Thereby if I have 2000 users so it will check for each user and then display me one friend which will eat up the cpu and also may take years if i have just 30 friends.

The code is given below.

```
database.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).child("friends")
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        list.clear();
                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            String friends = dataSnapshot2.getValue(String.class);
                            database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot1) {
                                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot1.getChildren()) {
                                        if (dataSnapshot.getKey().equals(friends)) {
                                            Users users = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                                            users.setUserId(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                                            list.add(users);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {
                    }
                });
```

This is a small part doing the whole work can someone please teach me the most efficient way of doing this task.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo no i dont have anything wrong in the code just the problem is that I want a more efficient way. My code checks each user and displays it in the recycle view if the uid is one of my friend uid in my friend list. The problem in the code is that if i have 200 users  using my app then it will check for 200 users and then display my friend. As you can see it will be a great head to wait for it to do such operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of tokens, and you have a folder where this tokens is the names of the folders where these users are stored, why do you parse the entire list looking for a match if you can just access the folder by token